# Grid View in angularjs and Html

Tags: angularjs, datagridview

I want to create a dynamic table with the filtering option, and when I click on a field we display popup contains the details of the field. How to do this?

Comment: Show your effort first.

Answer (score 0):

Quiz.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/w3.css">

<div class="w3-bar w3-border w3-light-grey" style="margin-top: 60px">
    <a href="Accueil.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-right">Accueil</a>
    <a href="contrat.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-right">Mes offres</a>
    <a href="candidature.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-right">Candidature</a>
    <a href="agenda.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-right">Agenda</a>
    <a href="Quizz.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-right">Quizz</a> </div> <div style="padding-right: 60px">
    <img src="../../styles/img/plus.png">
    <img src="../../styles/img/edit_contract.png">
    <img src="../../styles/img/save.png">
    <img src="../../styles/img/delete.png"> </div>
```

and QuizCtrl.js

[image]

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('QuizCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

Comment: Is this your answer or part of the question?